# How do I stub method_options using Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, command-line-interface, thor

```
Class CLI < Thor
  desc "run [age]" "user passes age"
  method_option :age,type:'numeric'
  def run
    variable=options[:a] if options[:a].present?
    call_method(a)
  end
end
```

How do I mock `options[:a]` using Rspec if I want to test the following line?

```rb
variable=options[:a] if options[:a].present?
```

Also, how do I test whether the local variable is updated or not?

Comment: Is `variable` used anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the "options"

```
  let(:cli) { CLI.new }
  allow(cli).to receive(:options){ { a:2 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions suggested here or other SO questions worked for me, but I found the solution here:
https://github.com/brianokeefe/blog/blob/master/2014-05-31-testing-thor-command-lines-with-rspec.md#handling-input

So you would do the test like this:

```
subject(:cli) { CLI.new }
it "should work" do
  cli.options = {:age => 2}
  expect { cli.run }.to ...
end
```